# Stop all networking between guest OS and Host OS

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, malware, analysis

I am using fedora on by virtual box as Guest OS for Malware Analysis.
The Host OS is windows 10. I will be unpacking malware/virus on guest OS.
But to ensure it doesn't cause any trouble with my Host OS, any form of networking should be disabled. How do I ensure that?

Some things that I have tried:

1. Disabled shared folder between windows and fedora
2. If I ping my eth0 IP address of windows from fedora, it doesn't work. I think that's a good sign. But not sure if that is enough to protect my Host OS (Windows 10)
   when I will be working on malware analysis on fedora.

Comment: Just disable the virtual network interface(s) the shared folders are an IP based technology, hence you disable them by disabling the network. Also make sure you have the latest version of VirtualBox installed as from time-to-time there are vulnerabilities found in VirtualBox that allow guests to execute code on the host OS.

Comment: How do you disable it ? I see an option `Enable Network Adapter` option under Settings->Network

Comment: And if the VM is not running you can disable it. Overwise just use the VM windows and disable it via Devices -> Network -> Network Adapter

Comment: Although little bit out of context. What's the analogy for this `Virtual Network Adapter`. Like for virtual interface it's like consider a physical device with a port in which a wire can be inserted. So disabling an interface of a device in a virtual way , can be thought of as `pulling of the wire from the port in physical device`. Not sure if this analogy is correct also.